# Word that would describe someone who is uncomfortably scrupulous towards others

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for and adjective which would describe someone who cares about something deeply, say grammar, and therefore is irritated by every little mistake when you write some text together. Something like "excessively prudent".

Comment: *pedantic* sounds close enough.

Comment: There is the slang term [*grammar nazi*](https://www.dictionary.com/e/pop-culture/grammar-nazi/) also for your specific example.

Answer (score 2):

[Pedantic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedantic) is precisely the word for this. Webster adds the following note:

> Pedantic is an insulting word used to describe someone who annoys others by correcting small errors, caring too much about minor details, or emphasizing their own expertise especially in some narrow or boring subject matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think these words are close enough:
*fastidious* - *conservative*

Comment: I don't think *conservative* is a good match - it's more about not liking change or new things than being excessively scrupulous. *fastidious* is better, although it doesn't have a negative connotation OP seems to imply.

Answer (score 0):

Priggish, prig (noun) (chiefly British)--Disapproving attitude of someone who annoys people by being very careful about proper behavior and by criticising the behavior of other people, e.g. 'Princess Margaret was always a bit of a prig.'